# Acknowledge the editor of a post

Tags: support, editing

First time editor so it can be I'm simply not getting the way this site copes with editing.

I have edited
https://askubuntu.com/questions/445325/trying-out-ubuntu-as-an-alternative-to-windows-xp and the edit was accepted. However, when you look at the post it seems like Ward Muylaert was the one who edited the post instead of me. 
[image]

I'm guessing he is the one who accepted my edit, but shouldn't it show my name instead of his? It's not like the reputation or something like that went to him so no problems there, but I find it weird that the editor doesn't get the credit.

Comment: TL;DR Ward Muylaert edited the same post after you edited it.  Possibly because he modified some of your edit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Revision history

All posts have a revision history that you can view - in this case:

- https://askubuntu.com/posts/445325/revisions

You'll note that you made an edit and immediately afterwards Ward made another edit - probably tidying up aspects that you had not made in your edit.

Sometimes the approver decides to improve the edit. This case the approver will be shown.

This its a matter of timing - you had made the edit, and the next person immediately made another edit or improved on the edit.

Thus - congrats - you have indeed got the credit ... you just need to be aware that the post just shows the very last editor.

Comment: @Timothy Sometimes the approver decides to improve the edit. This case the approver will be shown. He can also decide was the edit helpful or not – so you will gain rep if your edit was helpful.